# how to use operator overloading in Kotlin to divide a number by a numeric vector

Tags: kotlin, operator-overloading, extension-methods, type-parameter

I'm trying to recreate in Kotlin something I *believe* is possible in Pandas/Python. I would like to perform division such that a number (Int, Double, etc) is divided by a numeric vector. (I'm told this is possible, but haven't found a reference.) One example i've seen was part of a growth rate calculation

```
1.0 / data1['nYears']
```

Here 1.0 is divided by each value in data1['nYears'], and a column was returned containing the element-wise result. E.G., if the column contained 2 and 4, the result would be a new column containing .5 and .25.

Can this be done in Kotlin?

(FWIW, the reverse calculations (dividing a column by a scalar constant) are perhaps more important, but i thought i would start here.)

i found a partial solution in this using operator overloading with an extension function :

```
operator fun Int.div(vector: Vector<Int>) : Vector<Double> {
    val result = Vector("", ArrayList<Double?>())
    for (e in vector) {
        if (e == null) {
            result.add(null)
        } else {
            result.add(this / (e * 1.0))
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

This works fine for Ints, but when I attempted to extend it to other numeric types I ran into trouble.  For example, adding a similar method for doubles I got an error, i believe is caused by type erasure.

```
Platform declaration clash: The following declarations have the same JVM signature...
```

Next I tried providing a single method with an argument of (Vector ) to cover both cases, but got

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied
```

Is there a way to do this in Kotlin?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the names of the functions/operators are the same and would generate the same static Java function name. You can easily assign a new Java-name with the `@JvmName` annotation (see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#handling-signature-clashes-with-jvmname).

Here an example from the standard libs:

```
@JvmName("sumOfInt")
fun Iterable<Int>.sum(): Int { ... }

@JvmName("sumOfFloat")
fun Iterable<Float>.sum(): Float { ... }
```